# What's the difference between MaterialUserName and MaterialIdName in the IModelDoc2 interface?

Tags: c#, .net, solidworks

So I have this bit of code:

```
if ((strMaterial == null) || (strMaterial == ""))
            strMaterial = currDoc.MaterialUserName;
```

I know that my code passes through the if statement, because using

```
if ((strMaterial == null) || (strMaterial == ""))
            strMaterial = currDoc.MaterialIdName;
```

works. However, it returns some sort of string that looks like "SOLIDWORKS Materials|ANSI 304|1". 
My desired output is something like "ANSI 304".
I know I can just process that string to remove the parts, but I wanted to know the difference between those getters. Thanks!

Comment: From [this](https://www.fasetto.com/file/download/e7608f66b5cf44009c1157adc398734b) PDF: MaterialUserName is an user-friendly name and MaterialIdName is an internal ID.

Comment: @JeroenHeier yeah I got this information from the same book. MaterialUserName isn't getting me the material name despite my having set the Material to copper. Thanks!